# bootstrap modal window not closed immediately after 'Yes' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal window that I am using in my ASP.NET MVC application.
This modal window is parametrized, I can specify title and message text.

Below is the modal window, MyConfirmModalDialog.cshtml:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" 
     style="padding:0px;margin-left:0px;left:42%;min-width:15%">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" 
                        style="margin-top:-30px">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="confirmCancel">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirmOk">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This modal window is placed within another view using razor helper:

```
@Html.Partial("MyConfirmModalDialog");
```

Then I use it like below to show it to the user:

```
showConfirmation = function (title, message, success, cancel) {
    var modal = $("#confirmModalDialog");
    modal.find(".modal-title").html(title).end()
         .find(".modal-body").html(message).end()
         .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });

    var fClose = function () {
        modal.modal("hide");
    };

    modal.modal("show");

    $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', success).one('click', fClose);
    $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
};

function onPerformActions() {
    var title = "Warning";
    var message = "Do you wish to continue?";

    var success = function () {
        performActions();
    };

    var cancel = function () {
        // Do nothing
    };

    showConfirmation(title, message, success, cancel);
}
```

If user clicks on 'Yes' button, from success function I call the method peformActions as above code shows. Below method performActions, basically in performs an ajax asynchronous call to an action in the controller:

```
function performActions()
{
           $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DoActions", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea" })',
                type: "POST",                
                async: true,
                success: function (resp) {
                    // Do some things on success       
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Do some things on error
                }
            });
}
```

The problem I have is that modal window is not closed immediately when user clicks on 'Yes' button, it takes some seconds, and then this modal window is overlapped with the next modal window that is shown afterwards in the process.